# How to encapsulate a memory-mapped file into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector, mmap

In C++, on Linux, after I open a file with `open()` and then memory-map it with `mmap()`, I am given a `void*` that I can typecast to e.g. char* and read as desired.

But, suppose I want to use std::vector to access that data.  How could I accomplish that?

At first I thought I could make a custom allocator for my std::vector.  But I see two problems with that:

1. Its `allocate()` method will only receive a size argument.  That is insufficient, as it also needs to know the already-mapped address, rather than allocating a new one (as allocators usually do.)
2. Its `deallocate()` method -- to do this correctly -- would need to both unmap the buffer (easy, once #1 above is solved,) and `close()` the file descriptor (hard, since it has no way of knowing that value.)

I thought about maybe storing this metadata (existing mapped address, and file descriptor) in a known place to be referenced by my custom allocator, but that would not be thread-safe without complicating things with TLS.

Is the above possible some way?  Or ill-advised (if so, please explain)?  Is there perhaps some other standard-library class that would serve my purpose?

My reason for wanting to do this, is to avoid a raw/POD pointer in a class that interprets the binary data in that memory-mapped region.

Comment: How about a new `class`? Constructor gets filename and does the `open` and `mmap`, destructor the `munmap` and `close`. Then you add the methods you need, like `operator[]`, `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: @mch I was thinking the same thing. I made [this `Mmap` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53634081/7582247) that could be made into a `template` to iterate over non-`const` `T*`s instead. As long as the `T`s are trivial it should work.

Comment: That just kicks the can down the road.  Instead of having the raw pointer in my existing class, now I have it in the new class.   .... At least with std::span, it is someone else's class.  :)   In all seriousness, it sounds to me like `std::span` is the most idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell Yeah, for read-only access that'll do fine. What I meant with the `Mmap` class is that it could be used to do the mapping and provide and non-`const` `span`-like interface if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there perhaps some other standard-library class that would serve my purpose?

Yes: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) is a wrapper that provides container like access without ownership.